# Does FileStream.Flush(true) flush buffers for all instances associated with the physical file?

Tags: .net, file

I have two FileStream instances each having opened the same disk file simultaneously.  In each case the file is opened as share-all without specifying the WriteThrough flag.  I write to different locations using the two instances.  If I call Flush(true) on one of the instances will all data written by both FileStream instances be flushed to disk or only the data written using the instance on which Flush() was called?

Comment: It has pretty unusual powers, it pinvokes the [FlushFileBuffers() winapi function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-flushfilebuffers).  So not only the buffer that FileStream uses, it messes with the file system cache as well.  It is specific about what gets flushed, only the file and not everything.  Using it to flush the entire volume is something it can do as well, as documented, but isn't supported from a .NET program.  Creating a FileStream for a volume is not possible without pinvoking CreateFile, CAS gets in the way.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, FlushFileBuffers() is p-invoked using the Win32 HANDLE associated with the FileStream object.  Will a single call to FlushFileBuffers() cause all un-written file-cache buffers for the file to be committed to disk even if writes have occurred on several HANDLEs to the same physical file?

Comment: It is fairly likely, I can't give you a warranty.

Comment: Thanks for the input!